# XMLWriter with Reader doesn't work (hex 0xFFFF cannot be included in name)

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create my custom class serializer, but it gives me this error:

```php
XmlException: The '' character, hexadecimal value 0xFEFF, cannot be included in a name. Line 2, position 10.
```

```
    public void SaveClassObject(string _savePath, object obj)
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {Indent = true, NewLineOnAttributes = true};
        var fileStream = File.Open(_mainSavePath + _savePath + ".xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream!, settings);
        var reader = new XmlTextReader(fileStream!);
        
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        reader.MoveToContent();
        writer.WriteNode(reader, false);
        writer.WriteElementString("Type", obj.GetType().ToString());
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var getval = property.GetValue(obj);
            
            writer.WriteElementString(property.Name, getval.ToString());
        }
        writer.Flush();
        
        reader.Skip();
        reader.Read();
        
        writer.WriteNode(reader, false);

        var fields = obj.GetType().GetFields();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            var getval = field.GetValue(obj);
            
            writer.WriteElementString(field.Name, getval.ToString());
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Flush();
        
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: In the future, please add your code to the question and not linked-to on some external site.  This preserves the long-term value of your question in case the link goes bad.  As a courtesy I've done this for you.

Comment: Check the value of `_mainSavePath`

Comment: Thank you and sorry!

Comment: Hi user9938, the file is created as it should (so the _mainSavePath is not wrong)

Comment: Your reader and writer are both operating on the same `FileStream`. That won't work.

Comment: Multiple streams give me error "Sharing Violation"

Comment: Is there anything in the input file that is opened at `var fileStream = File.Open(_mainSavePath + _savePath + ".xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
`?

Comment: You are trying to write to and read from the same stream simultaneously.  Why are you trying to do this?  Can you share a [mcve] that fully reproduces the problem, with the preexisting XML and the `object obj` you are working with?  Maybe if you can share the input XML, the `object obj` and the desired output XML we could suggest alternative ways to get what you want.

Comment: I tried to create "node" for fields and properties of class (so that I can parse it as such). I cannot unfortunately give you reproducible example, because now I see it's completely wrong. I will post answer shortly about how I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is completely wrong.
I tried to turn this:

```cs
            var saveDataTest = new SaveDataTest
            {
                testInt = 44,
                testStr = "gdgsdgsg",
                testIntField = 88,
                testStrField = "rewetwef"
            };
```

Into this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SaveData>
  <Type>SinglePlayer.GameSaves.SaveHandler+SaveDataTest</Type>
  <Properties>
    <testInt>44</testInt>
    <testStr>gdgsdgsg</testStr>
  </Properties>
  <Fields>
    <testIntField>88</testIntField>
    <testStrField>rewetwef</testStrField>
  </Fields>
</SaveData>
```

The working code now looks like this:

```cs
        public void SaveClassObject(string _savePath, object obj)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(_mainSavePath + _savePath + ".xml")) File.Create(_mainSavePath + _savePath + ".xml").Close();
            
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {Indent = true, NewLineOnAttributes = true};
            var fileStream = File.Open(_mainSavePath + _savePath + ".xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream!, settings);

            var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
            
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("SaveData");
            
            writer.WriteElementString("Type", obj.GetType().ToString());
            
            writer.WriteStartElement("Properties");
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var getval = property.GetValue(obj);
                
                writer.WriteElementString(property.Name, getval.ToString());
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            var fields = obj.GetType().GetFields();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Fields");
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                var getval = field.GetValue(obj);
                
                writer.WriteElementString(field.Name, getval.ToString());
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            
            writer.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```